# Rmagick fails after Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i start rails server, server is not started 
It is showing following Error 
when i start rails server, server is not started 
It is showing following Error

```
/home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.0/lib/RMagick2.so (LoadError)
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.0/lib/rmagick_internal.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.0/lib/rmagick.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/workspace/hotel_management/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/workspace/hotel_management/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/workspace/hotel_management/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/effectech/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/effectech/workspace/hotel_management/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /home/effectech/workspace/hotel_management/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you install `imagemagick` in your system ?

Comment: Yes I have installed

Comment: I think its issue of gem rmagick

Comment: when i am installing 'gem install rmagick' it is showing this error

Comment: run `gem pristine rmagick` or `bundle update rmagick`

Comment: gem pristine rmagick or bundle update rmagick for this it is showing same error 
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: And you get above error when try this command `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` ?

Comment: And you get above error when try this command `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` ?

Comment: Its not working
Showing same error

Comment: so which error its shows ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems shared object changed its location after system upgrade. Try `gem uninstall rmagick` and then `bundle install` to compile it against current imagemagick version.

Comment: after bundle install
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.15.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Are you sure the system upgrade went ok?